# Using LayoutInflater and AlertDialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

Im trying to get an AlertDialog to inflate from a customview. I think I know what the problem is but I dont know how to fix it. I have a (View V) on LongClick and  Button1 is using "alertdialog" to find data. I'm getting a NullPointer Exception on line 
TextView stax1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xxx); 
The only thing that makes sense is I have the Dialog looking in "alerthelp" when it should looking in the activity it came from. How do I fix this?

```
        lay1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)        
        {                     

            LayoutInflater myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View dialogView = myLayout.inflate(R.layout.alerthelp, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            alertDialog.show();


            Button button1 = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView stax1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xxx);
                String sax1 = stax1.getText().toString();
                double sx1 = Double.parseDouble(sax1);

                TextView textviewlay1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1ab);
                String stringl1 = textviewlay1.getText().toString();
                 Double doubl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringl1);  

                TextView textviewp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                String stringp1 = textviewp1.getText().toString();
                Double intp1 = Double.parseDouble(stringp1);

                double resultl1 = intp1 - (doubl1*sx1);
                int precision21t = 100; //keep 4 digits
                resultl1= Math.floor(resultl1 * precision21t +.5)/precision21t;
                textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl1));     

            }
        }); 


            Button button2 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button2); 
            button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView textviewlay1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1ab);
                String stringl1 = textviewlay1.getText().toString();
                Double doubl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringl1);    

                TextView textviewp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                String stringp1 = textviewp1.getText().toString();
                Double intp1 = Double.parseDouble(stringp1);

                double resultl1 = intp1 - doubl1;
                int precision21t = 100; //keep 4 digits
                resultl1= Math.floor(resultl1 * precision21t +.5)/precision21t;
                textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl1));  
                }
                }); 

            Button button3 = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button3); 
            button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                TextView ss1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.s2);
                ss1.setText("st");

            }
        });


        Button button4 = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView ss1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.s2);
                ss1.setText("");


            }
        }); 



        Button button5 = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button5); 
        button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(xxxActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                MenuView1Activity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                MenuView1Activity.this.finish();
            }
        }); 

        Button button6 = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button6); 
        button6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(xxxActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                xxxActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                xxxActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        return false;   




        }});
```

Comment: I going to show my updated code. Now Lay1 onClick makes my screen just go slighty dark. Very Weird.

Comment: Someone help please...

Comment: Im going to delete this question guys. I need this really bad. I hope when I give you some up points for your help it doesnt go away because I deleted the question. I'm going to post it again and maybe ask a little differently.

Comment: Well I guess I cant delete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are trying to load text from static TextView. May be it should be EditText?

```
TextView stax1=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
String sax1 = stax1.getText().toString();
```

EDITED:

Try this code:

```
lay1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)        
        {                     

            LayoutInflater myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View dialogView = myLayout.inflate(R.layout.alerthelp, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            Button button1 = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView stax1=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
                String sax1 = stax1.getText().toString();
                double sx1 = Double.parseDouble(sax1);
                TextView textviewlay1 =(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.m1ab);
                String stringl1 = textviewlay1.getText().toString();
                 Double doubl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringl1);      
                TextView textviewp1 = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                String stringp1 = textviewp1.getText().toString();
                Double intp1 = Double.parseDouble(stringp1);
                double resultl1 = intp1 - (doubl1*sx1);
                int precision21t = 100; //keep 4 digits
                resultl1= Math.floor(resultl1 * precision21t +.5)/precision21t;
                textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl1));     

            }
        }); 

 return false;  




        }});
```

Comment: Button 1 performs a calculation. That textView is from another activity which starts out as an EditText but through intent and Shared Preferences is saved on the current page which opens up a dialog to do the calculation or some other choices.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and I'm getting the NullPointerException again right on line                 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){   Button 1 is defintely on XML alerthelp. I dont understand. I even erased my code and copied what you wrote....same thing

Comment: I do not miss those newbie growing pains.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
TextView stax1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xxx);
```

to

```
TextView stax1=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should change all the TextView after the dialog opens, right?

Comment: Yes. All the textviews which are in inflated view

Comment: Now I dont get anything from the LongClick. It does nothing

Comment: Did you try changing `Button button1 = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);` to `Button button1 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button1);` ? @SmulianJulian

Comment: When I do that I get no response from the OnClick of lay1. The Alert Dialog wont open, not that I've gotten to open anyway.