# How to show the LayoutInflater in alert message?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my code for layoutInflater in alert message. When running on device, only OK and CANCEL buttons appear. The popup.xml (for layout) does not exist.

This is my code

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(reconfirm.this);
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater
      = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
      .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false);

  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

      Intent intObj = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
          agree.class);
      startActivity(intObj);

    }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

      Intent intObj = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
          IntentExampleActivity.class);
      startActivity(intObj);

    }

  });
  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

  // show it
  alertDialog.show();
}
```

this is my popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="166dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.12"
    android:text="By using any of the websites" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.12"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="More" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.21"
    android:text="I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions." />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="114dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Using LayoutInflater and AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338362/using-layoutinflater-and-alertdialog)

It seems you are trying to load text from static TextView. May be it should be EditText?

```
TextView stax1=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
String sax1 = stax1.getText().toString();
```

EDITED:

Try this code:

```
lay1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)        
        {                     

            LayoutInflater myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View dialogView = myLayout.inflate(R.layout.alerthelp, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            Button button1 = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView stax1=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
                String sax1 = stax1.getText().toString();
                double sx1 = Double.parseDouble(sax1);
                TextView textviewlay1 =(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.m1ab);
                String stringl1 = textviewlay1.getText().toString();
                 Double doubl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringl1);      
                TextView textviewp1 = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                String stringp1 = textviewp1.getText().toString();
                Double intp1 = Double.parseDouble(stringp1);
                double resultl1 = intp1 - (doubl1*sx1);
                int precision21t = 100; //keep 4 digits
                resultl1= Math.floor(resultl1 * precision21t +.5)/precision21t;
                textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl1));     

            }
        }); 

 return false;  




        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivtyclass.this);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourpopuplayout);

final TextView textView1= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

dialog.show();
```

you can use this anywhere.And you can fully customize your alert dialog.